# Accessing protected members in base class objects

Tags: c++, inheritance, llvm-clang

Consider:

```
class A {
protected:
    int _i;
};

class B : public A {
    B(const B & object) {
        _i = object._i;
    };

    B(const A & object) {
        _i = object._i;
    };
};
```

First copy constructor is correct, because permissions are based on classes, not on objects. So I can reach protected members from my own class objects.
Why second constructor (or any similar method) raises compile time error?

In short: Why permission checking in C++ does not regard class inheritance rules in this case?

Also this was encountered in Apple LLVM-4.2 but not in Apple LLVM-4.1.

Comment: Please provide the error text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In short: Why permission checking in C++ does not regard class inheritance rules in this case?

You're asking for rationale behind the rule which prohibits the second constructor.

To understand the rationale, consider this code:

```
A a;
a._i = 100; //error, _i is protected
```

That is correct, and expected. So far, so good.

But **if** the second constructor is allowed (in your code), then anyone can write a class `modify` as:

```
struct modify : public A {
    void i(A & object, int newValue) {
        object._i = newValue; //MODIFY THE PROTECTED MEMBER of the argument!
    };
};
```

And then you can do this instead:

```
A a;
modify().i(a, 100); //okay, indirectly modify a._i !!!
std::cout << a._i << std::endl; //prints 100
```

If the second constructor can access the `protected` member of the argument, then `modify::i()` can also do the same! That way you actually modify the protected members!

Comment: Also, if that is allowed, then one can write a *generic* modifier class to modify *any* `protected` member of *any* class!